# biblatex-dw: special formatting @incollection before xref entry

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biblatex-dw

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
edstringincitations=false,
bibencoding=utf8,
mincrossrefs=0]{biblatex}

% ----------- mistake is somewhere in here ------------
%% bilbiography driver to display only shorttitle of referenced collection for incollection items
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:full}}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:label}}
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:extrainfo}}
    {}
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:full}{%
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printlist{organization}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:label}{%
    \entrydata{\strfield{crossref}}
    {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
        \printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        %\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield[shorttitle]{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:extrainfo}{%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}}

% ----------- mistake is somewhere above here ------------

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{albrechtbirkner,
    crossref = {kampmann},
    author = {Albrecht-Birkner, Veronika},
    title = {Die Zwei-Reiche-Lehre in der DDR: Vortrag im Rahmen der Tagung Die lutherische Zwei-Reiche-Lehre in politischen Kontexten des 20. Jahrhunderts},
    shorttitle = {Reiche},
    gender = {sf}
}
@incollection{banchelli2008,
    crossref = {cambi2008},
    author = {Banchelli, Eva},
    title = {Ostalgie: eine vorläufige Bilanz},
    shorttitle = {Ostalgie},
    gender = {sf}
}

@collection{cambi2008,
    year = {2008},
    title = {Gedächtnis und Identität: Die deutsche Literatur nach der Vereinigung},
    address = {Würzburg},
    isbn = {382603788X},
    editor = {Cambi, Fabrizio},
    shorttitle = {Gedächtnis},
    gender = {sm}
}

@collection{kampmann,
    year = {2017},
    title = {Angewandtes Luthertum?},
    address = {Gütersloh},
    isbn = {382603788X},
    editor = {Kampmann, Jürgen and Otte, Hans},
    shorttitle = {Luthertum},
    gender = {pp}
}
@incollection{pelz2015,
    crossref = {kampmann},
    year = {2017},
    title = {Von der Deutschen Demokratischen Repunlik zur deutschen Pastorenrepublik? Mecklenburgische und Pommersche, evangelisch-lutherische Predigten von 1989/90 als Spiegel der Interpretationen einer lutherischen Zwei-Reiche-Lehre im 20. Jahrhundert},
    author = {Pelz, Birge-Dorothea},
    shorttitle = {Kirche}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{pelz2015,banchelli2008,albrechtbirkner}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The editor of my book requested the following change:

[image]

1) There should be a dot after the @incollection entry has finished, not a comma.

2) The "in" should then start with capital letter "In".

3) The editor names of the collection should be written in normal font, not smallcaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:full}}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:label}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:extrainfo}}
    {}
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

should address 1) and 2). The relevant change is `\setunit{\addperiod\space}` instead of `\newunit` in the line before `\usebibmacro{in:}%`.

For 3) we can use

```
\newbibmacro{crossref:label}{%
  \entrydata{\strfield{crossref}}
  {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{##1}%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{##1}%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{##1}%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{##1}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
   \printfield[shorttitle]{labeltitle}}}
```

Where we simply reset `\mkbibnamefamily` and friends to add no formatting.